# Get output from EXE launched in Tcl and pause further processing until EXE finishes

Tags: process, tcl, wait

I'm launching a single EXE from a Tcl script, and would like to get the output from the EXE and display it using a simple PUTS command to provide user feedback.  At the moment, I am launching the EXE in a CMD window where the user can see the progress, and waiting for the EXE to create a file.  The first script here works whenever the output file LUC.CSV is created.

```
file delete -force luc.csv
set cmdStatus [open "| cmd.exe /c start /wait uc.exe"] 
while {![file exists "luc.csv"]} {
}    
# continue after output file is created
```

However, sometimes the file is not created, so I can't rely on this method.

I've been trying to get my head around the use of fileevent and pipes, and have tried several incarnations of the script below, but I'm obviously either missing the point or just not getting the syntax right.

```
puts "starting"
set fifo [open "| cmd.exe /c start  uc.exe" r] 
fconfigure $fifo -blocking 0 
proc read_fifo {fifo} { 
    puts "calling read_fifo" 
    if {[gets $fifo x] < 0} {
        if {[eof $fifo]} {
           close $fifo
        }
    }
    puts "x is $x" 
} 
fileevent $fifo readable [list read_fifo $fifo]
vwait forever  

puts"finished"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to launch a subprocess and do *nothing* else until it finishes, Tcl's `exec` command is perfect.

```
exec cmd.exe /c start /wait uc.exe
```

(Since you're launching a GUI application via `start`, there won't be any meaningful result unless there's an error in launching. And in that case you'll get a `catch`able error.) Things only get complicated when you want to do several things at once.

---

To make your original code work, you have to understand that the subprocess *has* finished. Tcl's just `vwait`ing `forever` because your code says to do that. We need to put something in to make the wait finish. A good way is to make the wait be for something to happen to the `fifo` variable, which can be unset after the pipe is closed as it no longer contains anything useful. (`vwait` will become eligible to return once the variable it is told about is *either* written to *or* destroyed; it uses a variable trace under the covers. It also won't *actually* return until the event handlers it is currently processing return.)

```
puts "starting"
# ***Assume*** that this code is in the global scope
set fifo [open "| cmd.exe /c start  uc.exe" r] 
fconfigure $fifo -blocking 0 
proc read_fifo {} {
    global fifo
    puts "calling read_fifo" 
    if {[gets $fifo x] < 0} {
        if {[eof $fifo]} {
            close $fifo
            unset fifo
        }
    }
    puts "x is $x" 
} 
fileevent $fifo readable read_fifo
vwait fifo

puts "finished"
```

That ought to work. The lines that were changed were the declaration of `read_fifo` (no variable passed in), the adding of `global fifo` just below (because we want to work with that instead), the adding of `unset fifo` just after `close $fifo`, the setting up of the `fileevent` (don't pass an extra argument to the callback), and the `vwait` (because we want to wait for `fifo`, not `forever`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Donal.  That code does work to run the script, but unfortunately the text that appears in the CMD window is not getting displayed.  Here's what I'm seeing as output: 

starting
calling read_fifo
x is 
finished

Comment: Woops - here's what I meant to say:Thanks for the quick reply, Donal.  That code does work to run the script, but unfortunately the text that appears in the CMD window (which I thought would appear as the variable "x" through use of [gets $fifo x] is not getting displayed.  Here's what I'm seeing as output: 

    starting
    calling read_fifo
    x is 
    finished

I'm also quite happy to go without the CMD window if I could display the text (which I thought I'd see from the puts "x is $x").  I'll have a play around with replacing the call to the CMD window with exec.

Comment: OK - I got it working just the way I wanted by using:   

set fifo [open "|  uc.exe" r]

Thank you very much!